# When should defensive copies be used in rust?

Tags: rust

I read this [article](https://adventures.michaelfbryan.com/posts/rust-best-practices/bad-habits/) explaining about common mistakes in rust. One of the last is "Defensive Copies" which say that values should not be copied when trying to acquire immutability.

As a beginner, i understood the reason, since only **one** mutable reference can exist **if** no other immutable reference exists, but after, the reason for people to use these copies when beginning is because of not enough familiarity with lifetimes.

Which lead me to look at my code and ask, when are copies valid? Should I copy when a value would be moved otherwise? And which are the other bad practices? (Also, is keyword escaping one of the bad practices?)

Comment: You seem to already know the answer to your title: due to Rust's referential guarantees you don't need to make copies *just as a precaution*.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we usually flag/close such questions as Opinion-based. Absorbing limiting beliefs from a random internet guy/gal is a bad practice. Assuming that human cognition is uniform and that a single standard can be a silver bullet is a bad practice. Some people would welcome a conformist programmer, others would shun him as such. Work from goals and not taboos. Use situational awareness.

Comment: An interesting angle on this is *structural sharing* in https://docs.rs/imbl/1.0.1/imbl/: "*if two data structures are mostly copies of each other, most of the memory they take up will be shared between them. This implies that making copies of an immutable data structure is cheap*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the article, you *shouldn't* use *defensive* copies.

The whole point of defensive copies in other languages is that, if you return a reference to "your" data, the receiver can do with it whatever they want. To 100% protect yourself against that, you resort to never returning a reference to your data but just a copy of it.

In Rust, with the ownership principle, the need for that just doesn't come up.